# One togglebutton controlling another togglebutton button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have five toggle buttons

When the first toggle button is pressed, all remaining toggle buttons should be checked

The first toggle button xaml wrote:

```
<ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="230" Height="95" Command="{Binding Path=AllCommand}" CommandParameter="All" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle.AllButtonStyle}">
<TextBlock Text="full agreement" />
</ToggleButton>
```

The rest of the toglebutton xaml wrote:

```
<ToggleButton  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="66" Height="66" Command="{Binding Path=Agree1Command}"  CommandParameter="Agree1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle.check1ButtonStyle}" />
```

```
  <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle.check1ButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d1d0cf" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d1d0cf" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background"  Value="#332c27" />
                <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

All togglebuton styles were applied equally as in the code

How can I check the other toggle button when I press the first toggle button?

be in desperate need of help

Comment: Could you just bind all button's IsChecked property to the same property on the viewmodel?

Comment: What do you mean by "check the other toggle"? How to get the value of all properties? Call CanExeсute for all commands? Implement validation in style triggers? Please specify exactly what you need. It also matters for the answer how your commands are implemented, whether they have a method for raising the CanExecuteChanged event. In your XAML, I have doubts - different commands and a unique string parameter for each command. With a high probability, this can be implemented either by different commands without a parameter, or by one command with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to my above comment. Hopefully this works for you. You could try something like the following. Basically this creates a view model for both the list of toggle buttons and the toggle buttons themselves. The command for each toggle button is bound to the command on the datacontext for the ItemsControl, not the ItemsSource. The command then calls a service that invokes an event when the buttons are modified (eg; when they are all checked). The main viewmodel subscribes to this event so that it can pull the modified view models from the service.

#### View

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{binding Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked = "{binding IsChecked}"
                        Text = "{binding ButtonText}"
                        IsChecked = "{binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickedCommand}"/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

#### Button View Model

```cs
public class ButtonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string buttonText;
    public int ButtonText
    {
        get => buttonText;
        set 
        { 
            myVar = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonText));
        }
    }
    
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set 
        { 
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked)) 
        }
    }
}
```

#### Main View Model

```cs
public class ListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel> Buttons { get; set; }

    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand;

    private readonly ToggleButtonService buttonService;

    public ListViewModel()
    {
        buttonService = new ToggleButtonClickedCommand(Buttons);
        buttonService.ButtonChecked =+ UpdateButtons
        ButtonClickedCommand = new ToggleButtonClickedCommand(buttonService);
    }

    private void UpdateButtons()
    {
        Buttons = buttonService.Buttons;
    }

}
```

#### Toggle button Service

```cs
public class ToggleButtonService
{

    private IEnumerable<ButtonViewModel> buttonViewModels;
    public IEnumerable<ButtonViewModel> ButtonViewModels
    {
        get { return buttons; }
        set 
        { 
            buttonViewModels = value;
            ButtonsChecked?.Invoke(); 
        }
    }
    
    public event Action ButtonChecked;

    public ToggleButtonService(IEnumerable<ButtonViewModel> buttons)
    {
        buttonViewModels = buttons;
    }

    public void SelectOrUnSelectAllButtons()
    {
        List<ButtonViewModel> Buttons = new List<ButtonViewModel>(ButtonViewModels);
        foreach(button in Buttons)
        {
            button.IsChecked = !button.IsChecked;
        }

        ButtonViewModels = Buttons;
    }
}
```

#### ToggleButton Clicked Command

```cs
public class ToggleButtonClickedCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ToggleButtonService ButtonService;

    public ToggleBUttonClickedCommand(ToggleButtonService buttonService)
    {
        ButtonService = buttonService;
    }

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public async void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        ButonService.SelectOrUnSelectAllButtons();
    }
}
```